# Starting Jenkins in Docker Container

Tags: jenkins, docker, centos7

I want to run Jenkins in a Docker Container on Centos7.
I saw the official documentation of Jenkins:
First, pull the official jenkins image from Docker repository.

```
docker pull jenkins
```

Next, run a container using this image and map data directory from the container to the host; e.g in the example below /var/jenkins_home from the container is mapped to jenkins/ directory from the current path on the host. Jenkins 8080 port is also exposed to the host as 49001.

```
docker run -d -p 49001:8080 -v $PWD/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home -t jenkins
```

But when I try to run the docker container I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh: line 25: /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log: Permission denied
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: It works ok. Do you have a write permission to where the container is being run?

Comment: I think it's an issue with that. I think I have to make sure that the container may write something on my host

Comment: yes you definitely allow the container to write on the host if you want to make it persistent.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The official Jenkins Docker image [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/) says regarding volumes:

> ```
> docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /your/home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins
> ```
>
> This will store the jenkins data in /your/home on the host. Ensure that /your/home is accessible by the jenkins user in container (jenkins user - uid 1000) or use -u some_other_user parameter with docker run.

This information is also found [in the Dockerfile](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/83ce6f6070f1670563a00d0f61d04edd62b78f4f/Dockerfile#L8).
So all you need to do is to ensure that the directory `$PWD/jenkins` is own by *UID* `1000`:

```
mkdir jenkins
chown 1000 jenkins
docker run -d -p 49001:8080 -v $PWD/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home -t jenkins
```

Comment: I still get an error: **Unable to create the home directory ‘/media/mydrive/JENKINS_HOME’. This is most likely a permission problem.**

Comment: i.e. ANSWER: Make the dir /your/home owned by UID 1000 on docker server (to match the jenkins user(UID=1000) in jenkins container. Add a jenkins user (with UID=1000) on docker server if needed..

Comment: How to I make sure UID 1000 owns that folder?

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu that's what `chown 1000 jenkins` does, it changes the owner of the directory `jenkins` to the user with UID 1000

Comment: I do not sure UID 100 ( 100 not 1000 - Dockerfile Thmasleveil linked to is 100). 
But I run `chown 100 jenkins`, everything work.
And after that I exec to container as link on browser to check password.
It's work with may case.

Answer (score 0):

The newest Jenkins documentation says to use Docker 'volumes'.
Docker is kinda tricky on this, the difference between the two is a full path name with the -v option for bind mount and just a name for volumes.

```
docker run -d -p 49001:8080 -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home -t jenkins
```

This command will create a docker volume named "jenkins-data" and you will no longer see the error.

Link to manage volumes:
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/