# How to give folder ownership to user with UID 1000?

Tags: linux

The reason I need to give folder ownership to UID 1000 is to make sure Docker container can write to the mounted volume based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706077/starting-jenkins-in-docker-container).

But the answer assumes reader knows how to change ownership. I don't know. After some research, I know how to change ownership [with this](https://www.techonthenet.com/linux/commands/chown.php), but can't make it work.

```
chown UID 1000 /u ./jenkins_home
```

My above command doesn't work. How do I change ownership to UID 1000???

Comment: `chown :1000 jenkins_home`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The accepted answer does explain how to change ownership.
The correct command would be `chown 1000 ./jenkins_home`.